# Does EEG biofeedback brain training can cause any harm?

Tags: eeg, brain-training, brain-computer-interface

I'm a hobbyist making BCI for biofeedback training.
Can I induce any damage to my brain by EEG brain training? For instance, by using wrong training protocols.. Be the way, it would be wonderful if someone can point me to any good sources of information on this topic (training protocols, algorithms, etc.)